# How to add flying screen in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing windows phone app. I would like to add fly screen init. Means when user click on button then without disturbing running page screen with list of all menu should come. this list of menu is in list box with 3 columns in it
Problem: how to add such screen?

Answer (score 0):

When clicking the button, a Storyboard should be started.

In a storyboard, you can say that a property of the menu should be animated (e.g. animate property X of TranslateTransform from -480 to 0 to flow in from the left).

This channel 9 video demonstrates storyboards and how to start and stop them via C#: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-22-Animating-the-Reel-Grid-with-a-Storyboard